# OAuth 2.0: Resending the Refresh Token

Tags: php, oauth, google-analytics, oauth-2.0

I'm using OAuth 2.0 via PHP to offer users access to their Google Analytics data as part of a CMS.  I've programmatically selected "offline" mode so I receive an access token and a refresh token once authenticated.  When the access token expires, I use the refresh token to obtain a new access token.  All is well and things are working great.

The problem is that some of my app's users have two or more [legitimate] accounts with my app:

```
account_1@myapp.com
account_2@myapp.com
```

And both need to have access to data from the same Google account:

```
account@google.com
```

When they first authorize account_1@myapp.com to access account@google.com's data, an access token AND a refresh token get sent back as expected.  But then when they try to authorize account_2@myapp.com, only an access token gets sent back (presumably because the refresh token has already been issued by Google).

Is there any way to request the refresh token again without resetting it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored adding approval_prompt=force to the authorization request?  See [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/oauth2-dev/browse_thread/thread/d818d71cddcc3278) on the Google OAuth 2 group.

Comment: The problem with forcing authorization again is that the original refresh token will no longer be valid.  I was hoping to discover a method to resend the original refresh token, but I don't think it's possible at this point.